# How do I use a Custom Service in a Web Service Listener Source?

Tags: mirth

I'd like to use a custom service in a Web Service Listener source, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Do I need to write a custom class or interface?
Does that class need to extend or implement anything specific?

After implementing the custom class does the wsdl change or does it use the same wsdl either way?

I'm using Mirth Connect 2.0.1.5164.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom class based off of the com.mirth.connect.connectors.ws.DefaultAcceptMessage class.

The easiest way is to download the source code, get Mirth to compile from source, and create a new class from the associated java files needed for this class, eg.

com.somecompany.mirth.connect.connectors.ws.MyAcceptMessage (or something simpler if needed)

You can then customize this class and change the parameters it accepts.

The WSDL will reflect the updated interface.

Frans